# Postgres taking up a lot of CPU

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a DB running postgres. 
Here is the mem usage of the server

```
52762 root      20   0   49824  32476   1032 R  92.7  0.0  13:15.95 find                                                              
49740 postgres  20   0 33.644g 6.747g 6.122g R  58.5  6.1  47:29.33 postgres                                                          
49644 postgres  20   0  538388 345552    628 S  40.9  0.3  27:06.48 postgres                                                          
49744 postgres  20   0 33.434g 5.799g 5.392g S   0.7  5.3   2:16.77 postgres                                                          
49765 postgres  20   0 33.434g 5.906g 5.501g S   0.7  5.4   2:54.68 postgres
```

Here is the pg_stat_activity

```
mps_schools=> SELECT pid, datname, usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity;
  pid  |   datname   | usename  |                                         query                                         
-------+-------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 53335 | mps_schools | mps      | select userid,username,name,imageurl,mtop,mleft from student where username='support'
 53022 | mps_schools | mps      | SELECT pid, datname, usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity;
 49740 | mps_schools | postgres | <insufficient privilege>
 49744 | mps_schools | postgres | <insufficient privilege>
 49765 | mps_schools | postgres | <insufficient privilege>
```

There are no such queries running then how is postgres taking up so much CPU. Also, what is the insufficient privilege>     query?

Comment: I'd start by making sure that username has an index and that you've rebuilt all indexes recently.  The insufficient privilege means just that - the mps user doesn't have permission to see what the postgres user is doing.

Comment: i just rebuilt all indexes

Comment: 1) Does the query give the correct result? 2) check the query plan (explain analyze) 3) you have a lot of memory

Comment: I bet you've got the db set for 32GB Shared memory buffers huh?

Comment: yes db is set to 32GB